# send postMessage from the web script to frame-script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, postmessage, e10s

On the frame-script.js, i cannot catch / listen to postMessages from the web scripts on the web page (nor to custom events).

However, i tried and was able to catch 'click' events.

What am i doing wrong?

post messaging like this :

```
window.postMessage(message, "*");
```

listening on the frame-script:

```
addEventListener("message", dosomething, false);
```

also tried

```
content.addEventListener("message", dosomething, false);
```

doesn't catch the postMessage.

Answer (score 0):

for extensions [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) has a 4th, proprietary argument to get untrusted events.